# npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install, yo

How can I fix this? I also tried the master version and got a similar error. I am using OSX Yosemite:

```
bash-3.2$ yo meanjs
You're using the official MEAN.JS generator.
? What mean.js version would you like to generate? 0.4.0
0.4.0
? In which folder would you like the project to be generated? This can be changed later. mean
Cloning the MEAN repo.......
? What would you like to call your application? MEAN
? How would you describe your application? Full-Stack JavaScript with MongoDB, Express, AngularJS, and Node.js
? How would you describe your application in comma seperated key words? MongoDB, Express, AngularJS, Node.js
? What is your company/author name? University of Wisconsin-Madison/Mona Jalal
? Would you like to generate the article example CRUD module? Yes
? Would you like to generate the chat example module? Yes
Running npm install for you....
This may take a couple minutes.
Error: Command failed: cd mean && npm install
npm WARN deprecated phantomjs@2.1.3: Package renamed to phantomjs-prebuilt. Please update 'phantomjs' package references to 'phantomjs-prebuilt'
npm WARN deprecated lodash@0.9.2: Grunt needs your help! See https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/1403.
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs version 3 and before will fail on newer node releases. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible.
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@2.0.3: graceful-fs version 3 and before will fail on newer node releases. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible.
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.8: graceful-fs version 3 and before will fail on newer node releases. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible.
npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.0.2: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^4.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated npmconf@2.1.2: this package has been reintegrated into npm and is now out of date with respect to npm
npm WARN prefer global jshint@2.8.0 should be installed with -g
npm WARN prefer global node-inspector@0.10.2 should be installed with -g
npm WARN prefer global node-gyp@3.3.1 should be installed with -g
npm WARN mongodb-core@1.2.31 requires a peer of kerberos@~0.0 but none was installed.
npm ERR! Darwin 14.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v5.8.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.7.3
npm ERR! path /Users/mona/interviews/mean/mean/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/bin/node-pre-gyp
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall chmod

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/Users/mona/interviews/mean/mean/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/bin/node-pre-gyp'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/Users/mona/interviews/mean/mean/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/bin/node-pre-gyp'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/mona/interviews/mean/mean/npm-debug.log

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:202:12)
    at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:850:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:323:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:7)
    at Pipe._onclose (net.js:475:12)
bash-3.2$
```

Comment: Do you have the latest meanjs generator? What does `npm ls -g --depth 0 2>/dev/null | grep generator-meanjs` show?

Comment: `npm ls -g --depth 0 2>/dev/null | grep generator-meanjs
├── generator-meanjs@0.4.4`

Answer (score 1):

According to the [`meanjs` readme](https://github.com/meanjs/mean/blob/d5c6c8eb909c8d563b283501d1f66debd1340217/README.md), node v5 is not supported yet. So you will probably need to downgrade to node v4 (LTS) or try your luck with the `meanjs` master branch and see if enough progress has been made yet to support node v5.

Comment: I did all that and ended up with some other error http://pastebin.com/3DtTA5WY can you please have a look and guide me in realizing what I am doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35983633/error-command-failed-bin-sh-c-cd-mean-npm-install